# Django Custom Text Formatting

Tags: python, django

How can I have add text formatting options in Django-Admin, either by coding it, or does django has addition features for it?

For eg: making a text bold, subscript, superscript, etc.

Comment: Also if you could tell me how can I write greek symbols in there.

Comment: or how to include both |safe and |linebreak options in template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to look at [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor). I cannot say for sure whether it provides all of the features that you require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.